# For Loop Construction Turned Functional

Tags: for-loop, functional-programming, scheme, racket, nested-loops

I am currently learning Racket and want to do the following simple task: Construct a list which contains all tuples `(i,j) : Int * Int`  with `0 <= i < N` and `0 <= j < M`.

In, let's say Python, I would immediately know how to approach this, by using *for* loops:

```py
# Not using any modules on purpose here
a = []
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(6):
        a.append((i,j))
```

But I have trouble doing this in Racket. By now I have found a solution which replicates the *for*-loop approach by using a recursively defined function which for `a : A` and `f : Int -> A -> A` satisfies the equations

```
for 0 a f = (f 0) a
for n a f = for (n-1) ( (f n) a ) f
```

which results in a chain of applications: `for n a f = ( (f 0) ∘ ... ∘ (f n) )(a)`. (By `f ∘ g`  I mean composition of `f` and `g`). So first `f n` is applied to `a`, then `f (n - 1)` to the result of that, etc.

Given I basically want to do something like `((f 0 0) ∘ (f 0 1) ∘ ... ∘ (f N M)) (a)`, it can be split up as:

```
 (((f 0 0) ... (f 0 M)) ∘ ... ∘ ((f N 0) ... (f N M))) (a)
= ((λz. for M z (f 0)) ∘ ... ∘ (λz. for M z (f N))) (a)
= for N a (λi z. for M z (f i))
```

Which then translates to the following Racket code:

```lisp
(define (for n a f)   ;; (for n '() cons) = range(n) = (0 1 ... n-1)
    (if (< 0 n) 
        (for (- n 1) (f (- n 1) a) f) 
        a))
        
(define a '())
(define (append i j x) (cons (cons i j) x))

(for 5 a (λ(i x) 
       (for 6 x (λ(j y) 
              (append i j y)))))
```

The answer produces the desired result and is at least nice regarding that it is obvious how to extend this construction with any number of additional loops.

But I am still wondering whether there isn't a neater functional way to do this.

I'm happy with any answer  that does or does not use functions which might already be present in some library and which I have simply missed so far.

Comment: your translation calculates the indices correctly, but is backwards on the execution order: `(f 0 0)` should be executed before `(f 0 1)` before .... `(f N M)`. try `(define (append i j x) (display (list i j)) (cons (cons i j) x))` and see. :) nice question!

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for [`for*/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2A%2Flist%29%29):

```
(for*/list ([i (range 5)]
            [j (range 6)])
  (list i j))
```

See also Racket guide for [Iterations and Comprehensions](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html).

Answer (score 2):

The [`for*/$@!` forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71092408/16981884) are compact, but Scheme ("Programming languages should be designed not by piling feature on top of feature...") is still there:

```
(define (range-pairs m n)  ;; Nat Nat -> (Listof (Cons Nat Nat))
  ;; produce (range m) ⨯ (range n)
  (do ([i (sub1 m) (sub1 i)]
       [a '() (do ([j (sub1 n) (sub1 j)]
                   [a a (cons (cons i j) a)])
                ((negative? j) a))])
    ((negative? i) a)))
```

Answer (score 2):

One perhaps-nice way of thinking about this is to realise that this is a counting problem but the base for each digit can vary.  So in the case you give this is counting in base `(N M)`: the low-order digit is base `N` and the high-order digit is base `M`.

So, the first thing is to write a function which will increment numbers like this, with the obvious representation of a number being a list of digits.  Here's one approach to that:

```
(define (increment-digits digits bases overflow)
  ;; Increment a number represented as a list of digits, where each digit is
  ;; in the corresponsing base.  On overflow return overflow.
  (let ripple ([ds digits]
               [bs bases]
               [rs '()]
               [carry? #t])
    (if (null? ds)
        ;; End of the digits
        (if carry?
            overflow
            (reverse rs))
        (match-let ([(cons d mds) ds]
                    [(cons b mbs) bs])
         (define nd (+ d (if carry? 1 0)))
         (if (= nd b)
             (ripple mds mbs (cons 0 rs) #t)
             (ripple mds mbs (cons nd rs) #f))))))
```

So now:

```
> (increment-digits (increment-digits '(0 0) '(2 2) #f) '(2 2) #f)
'(0 1)
```

Now, we can use this function to construct a stream of all the numbers in one of these per-digit bases:

```
(define (digit-stream bases)
  (let increment ([digits (make-list (length bases) 0)])
    (if digits
        (stream-cons digits
                     (increment (increment-digits digits bases #f)))
        empty-stream)))
```

Note that such a stream is completely lazy since `stream-cons` is lazy: it's not computed until you need it.  So, for instance, you can happily say:

```
(digit-stream '(1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000))
```

which is a stream with 10^24 elements.  And things like

```
(stream-ref (digit-stream '(1000000 1000000 1000000 1000000)) 1000000)
```

will work fine (it is `(0 1 0 0)` of course).

So now it merely remains to turn such a stream into a list:

```
> (stream->list (digit-stream '(2 5)))
'((0 0) (1 0) (0 1) (1 1) (0 2) (1 2) (0 3) (1 3) (0 4) (1 4))
```

Comment: ... and to do what the OP was asking, you only need to `(stream-map (lambda(i j) (f i j)) (digit-stream bases))`. :) the idea of unrolling the loops into one is nice. `increment-digits` is not a good name though. it suggests individual digits are incremented.  `digits-increment` seems clearer, to me. but, your enumeration order is flipped, i.e. your numbering is little-endian while the OP asked for the big-endian enumeration. perhaps you should use the reversed list of bases, and then reverse each index pairing, to get what the OP wanted.

Comment: or use `(stream-map (lambda(j i) (f i j)) (digit-stream (reverse bases)))`.

Comment: (note to myself: applicative non-monadic nested loops can be unrolled into one)

Answer (score 2):

Martin's answer is spot on.

Here are a few alternatives.

The first one is the most direct translation of the original Python:

```
(append*
  (for/list ([i 5])
    (for/list ([j 6])
       (list i j))))
```

The `(for/list clauses expression)` collects the values produced by `expression` in a list. The clauses are used to generate values that can be used in the expression.

The clause `[i 5]` is short for `[i (in-range 5)]` and will bind `i` to the values `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` in order.

Thus

```
(for/list ([i 5])
   i)
```

will produce the list `(0 1 2 3 4)`.

And similarly

```
(for/list ([i 5])
  (for/list ([j 6])
     (list i j)))
```

will produce the list `(((0 0) (0 1) (0 2) ... (0 5)) ((1 0) ... (1 5)) ... ((4 0) ... (4 5)))`.

Since you don't want a list of lists, but a single list, using `append*` will give you a single list instead.

Since nested lists are so common, one can use the `for*` variant instead:

```
(for*/list ([i 5] [j 6])
   (list i j))
```

This will run through the the clauses in a nested fashion.

For comparison, try:

```
(for/list ([i 5] [j 6])
   (list i j))
```

which will run through the clauses in parallel.

The result of the last example is `((0 0) (1 1) (2 2) (3 3) (4 4))`.

Note that the looping stops when any of the clauses runs out of values.

Answer (score 2):

For another pure-Scheme solution, you can use nested applications of `(map)` to accomplish the same thing.

```
(map (lambda (i)
       (map 
        (lambda (j)
          (list i j)) 
        (range 0 6 1))) 
     (range 0 5 1))
```

For strictness' sake, I have also implemented a somewhat overly elaborate `(range)` function to support this.

```
(define (range start end step)
  "Generates a list of integers from 'start' to 'end', stepping by 'step' values."
  (cond 
   ((= 0 step)
    '())
   ((or
     (and (< step 0)
          (< end start))
     (< start end))
    (cons start (range (+ start step) end step)))
   (else '())))
```

The output of this in `#lang racket` is:

```
'(((0 0) (0 1) (0 2) (0 3) (0 4) (0 5))
  ((1 0) (1 1) (1 2) (1 3) (1 4) (1 5))
  ((2 0) (2 1) (2 2) (2 3) (2 4) (2 5))
  ((3 0) (3 1) (3 2) (3 3) (3 4) (3 5))
  ((4 0) (4 1) (4 2) (4 3) (4 4) (4 5)))
```

Comment: you could replace the first `map` with `append-map`, to get the output that the OP wanted.